# I want to perform mean of a set of data after importing these data from computer in mathematica. But unable. pls help

Tags: data, data-acquisition, averages

I have used the following code in mathematica to perform mean to set of data.

```
Sig = N[Mean[Table[Transpose[Import[data[[i]],"Table",NumberPoint -> ","]][[2]], {i, 3, 8}]]]
```

But this works only for integer data and provide output, but for real numbers it provides output without performing calculation. like: I want the average of 2.2  and 4.4, which is 3.3, but mathematica shows 0.5(2.2+4.4) instead of 3.3.

How to solve this problem?

Please help me.

Comment: Look at the `FullForm` of your output. It looks like you are working with strings rather than numbers. [`ToExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToExpression.html) might be of use. Or you may want to change how you are doing the `Import`

Comment: No, I am not dealing with strings. I just try to perform mean of a set of data which aer numbers only, but mathematica is unable to perform mean when I wrote that code. it just shows the data how to do mean?

Comment: Post the [`FullForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullForm.html) of your output that looks like `0.5(2.2+4.4)`